# How to store standard composition Classes in ObjectBox?

Tags: flutter, dart, objectbox

I have **Class A** contains **List of Class B** that contains **List of Class C**
so how I would achieve this in ObjectBox ? how do I store it?

in the pic below you can see that I have **`BasicInfo Class`** Contains **`Data class`** and so on....

I put **@Entint**y annotation on **`BasicInfo class`** and after generating the models **`class D`** doesn't show up in the
**`objectbox.g.dart`** file as it's on of BasicInfo properties

```
  ModelEntity(
  id: const IdUid(1, 3501283007979667013),
  name: 'BasicInfo',
  lastPropertyId: const IdUid(1, 2073579066569957521),
  flags: 0,
  properties: <ModelProperty>[
    ModelProperty(
        id: const IdUid(1, 2073579066569957521),
        name: 'id',
        type: 6,
        flags: 1)
  ],
  relations: <ModelRelation>[],
  backlinks: <ModelBacklink>[])
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're saying `Class A` **contains** a `List of Class B`, then their relationship isn't a subclass/superclass but it's a standard composition. I understand your definition looks somewhat like this:

```dart
class A {
  List<B> bs;
}

class B {
  List<C> cs;
}

class C {}
```

And in order to use it in ObjectBox, you can define them as [relations](https://docs.objectbox.io/relations), either a standalone `ToMany` relation, or a `ToOne` relation with a backlink - depends on what better describes your data, you can achieve the same with both.

#### 1st alternative - using ToMany

`ToMany` relation stores the info in a separate "table" of IDs, like: `A.id <--> B.id` and another one  between `B.id <--> C.id`.

```dart
@Entity()
class A {
  int id;
  final bs = ToMany<B>();
}

@Entity()
class B {
  int id;
  final cs = ToMany<C>;
}

@Entity()
class C {
  int id;
}
```

#### 2nd alternative - using ToOne with a backlink

`ToOne` relation can achieve the same in your case and the relatin info is actually stored on the object itself as a single ID, i.e. there's a hidden `int B.classAId` field that and you can get all `Bs` for a class `A` instance by looking for those `Bs` pointing to this `A`. This is done behind the scenes by a `ToMany<>` with a `Backlink()` annotation.

```dart
@Entity()
class A {
  int id;

  @Backlink()
  final bs = ToMany<B>();
}

@Entity()
class B {
  int id;
 
  final a = ToOne<A>; 

  @Backlink()
  final cs = ToMany<C>;
}

@Entity()
class C {
  int id;

  final b = ToOne<B>; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vaind!
yes you are correct about that, and it's my bad to call it subclass, I'll fix it now.

So in my case there will be a for loop inside one another, to store the composite classes, and take the Id of first class and pass it as Target to the other class, right?

Comment: hard to tell what exactly you mean without a bit of code but it sounds reasonable :)